# How to get Categories of custom extension or third party component

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, category, subcategories

I have a thirdparty component which stores its categories in `#__categories` table.

```
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | extension      | title                 | alias                 | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_content    | Uncategorised         | uncategorised         | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_banners    | Sample Data-Banners   | sample-data-banners   | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_newsfeeds  | Sample Data-Newsfeeds | sample-data-newsfeeds | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_contact    | Sample Data-Contact   | sample-data-contact   | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_content    | Joomla!               | joomla                | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | com_thirdparty | ThirdParty Category   | thridparty-category   | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
...  | ...            | ...                   | ...                   | ...
-----+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
```

I can print categories from `com_banners` or from other core components as below,

```
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Banners');
$subCategories = $categories->get()->getChildren(true);
print_r($subCategories);
```

But it shows

> "**Fatal error**: Class 'ThirdPartyCategories' not found in ...\libraries\legacy\categories\categories.php on line 152"

when trying to print the categories of another extension as below,

```
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('ThirdParty');
$subCategories = $categories->get()->getChildren(true);
print_r($subCategories);
```

What do I have to do with the legacy categories in joomla libraries ?

> Note: The name `ThirdParty` is just a placeholder, could be any third
>   party extension's name.

Comment: Is `ThirdParty` the actual name of the component?

Comment: No, it's just a placeholder, could be any third party extension's name. In my case, it's com_thirdparty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some research, it turns out that the third party component I am using doesn't have a file created as `..\components\com_thirdparty\helpers\category.php`  which is required to implement a class `ThirdPartyCategories` which extends `JCategories` in the component's helpers directory as described below

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * ThirdParty Component Category Tree
 */
class ThirdPartyCategories extends JCategories
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   array  $options  Array of options
     */
    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        $options['table']      = '#__thirdparty';
        $options['extension']  = 'com_thirdparty';
        $options['statefield'] = 'published';
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've suitably answered you own question, please set it as your chosen answer to remove it from the unanswered questions list.